# BYpassing anti-WiFi protocols

Tags: windows-10, router, lan, wifi-configuration

At my university we have super fast LAN internet in the hostels, but no WiFi available. Many students have used their laptops to create Hotspots, but they face the penalty of a fine should they ever be caught. My question is whether there is a way to spoof the network/create a hotspot that cannot be discovered.

The IT technicians are obviously very secretive about the way their system works, but from what we can figure out is that they walk through the hostels and search for WiFi hotspots. When they find one that isn't theirs, they attempt to connect, and by doing so uncover the IP behind the network, pointing to the physical computer and port which it is connected to, and they shut it off.

Is this a possible way of doing so, or could they monitor the traffic on the physical port and flag a hotspot according to that? And is there any way to get around either of these scenarios?

Many Thanks

PS: I'm not the most tech savvy person when it comes to hardware, so please excuse any incompetence.

Comment: there is most probably a very good reason why the technicians do this, you should really follow the rules my friend

Comment: This is more generally applicable to hiding any wifi portal and keeping others from seeing & attempting to connect to it - why not search for that? Did you search for answers to this Q specifically, and what did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you cannot really hide such a "hotspot". You can only make it more difficult to see. Depending on the skill of the administrators and technicians, and depending on the time they spend, they will find it.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Claude Frantz. You could make a hotspot harder to detect by limiting its transmission power (if it has such a setting available). You could make it connectable by only you (and optionally people authorized by you) by choosing strong encryption settings.

But none of this offers complete protection if the network technicians happen to have a directional Wi-Fi antenna (you can make one from a Pringles can!), a simple receiver and a signal strength meter.

In a technically-oriented university, the network technicians might have talked to a professor at the local Radio Lab (or equivalent) and got to borrow some nice lab-quality equipment that can do the job. Or their secret weapon might simply be a cheap Wi-Fi signal detector from China: it might have shorter range, but in a dense hostel that might actually be an advantage. The only sure way to protect against this kind of location-finding efforts is to *not be transmitting* - that is, to not have an useful hot spot in the first place.

If there is an "official" university Wi-Fi network that's built using enterprise-grade Wi-Fi hardware, the base stations of that network might even be configured to also detect and automatically report any unauthorized hot-spots to the network admins. If two or more base stations can hear the same hot-spot, they might even be able to automatically triangulate the position of the hot-spot and show it on the building floorplan.

Comment: Many other students have gotten away with their hotspots by only having them on when they need them most (which obviously makes sense), but I was hoping there was a way to make it completely undetectible.  There is an Official WiFi network as well, but it does not extend to my residence, So I'm sure they come around and manually scan for networks. Thanks for the assistance